# What this function do?

Tags: c#

Its looks like that this function return the first array number but u don't know if this is the concept

```
public int w(int[] arr)
{
    int c = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        bool u = true;

        for (int j = 0; (j < i) && u; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                u = false;
        }

        if (u)
        {
            c++;
        }                
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: It counts all unique elements in an array.

Comment: So people are writing pre-obfuscated code these days?

Comment: looks like a decompile of obfuscated .net assembly

Comment: @Heuster it doesn't count the unique elements, it returns the distinct count of elements. `{ 1, 2, 3 }` returns 3, `{ 1, 1, 2, 3}` also returns 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function counts all distinct elements in an array.

The outer loop loops over all array elements. The inner loop loops over the array until the element of the outer loop. The count is incremented if **there is no preceding element which is similar to the current element**.

For instance, given the array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5]
```

The value of `c` will be

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5
```

so the result is `5`, which is the number of distinct elements in the array.

Comment: No, the number of `unique` elements in your case is 4. The `distinct` count of elements in your case is 5.

Comment: @Abbas thanks, I reworded.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by *Heuster*, this function returns the distinct number of elements in the array. This function gives the same result as following LinQ-expression:

```
var myIntegers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5 };
var distinctCount = myIntegers.Distinct().Count();
//distinctCount is '5'
```

More reading:

- [**Enumerable.Distinct Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)